# Parameterization issue in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am looking to parameterize something like this `API${version}Name.jmx`.

So that version will be changed with value I pass during runtime of image.

So if I pass "5" during runtime it should replace with "API5Name.jmx" but now it is getting replaced as "APIName.jmx".

I tried with `${}` and `$` but the value is not getting replaced.

Is there any way to do this?

Please guide me on this.

Below is my sh file to run docker:

```
environmentName=$1
threadUser=$2
rampUpPeriod=$3
loopCount=$4
version=$5

docker build --no-cache=true -t jmeterimage -f Dockerfile.txt .
docker run -d --name jmimages -e "ENVIRONMENTNAME=${environmentName}" -e "THREADUSERS=${threadUser}" -e "RAMPUPPERIOD=${rampUpPeriod}" -e "LOOPCOUNT=${loopCount}" -e "VERSION=${version}" -t jmeterimage
```

Below is the **dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

ARG environmentName
ARG threadUsers
ARG rampUpPeriod
ARG loopCount
ARG version

ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.4.1"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL  https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
# ENV ENVIRONMENTNAME=${environmentName}
# ENV THREADUSERS=${threadUsers}
# ENV RAMPUPPERIOD=${rampUpPeriod}
# ENV LOOPCOUNT=${loopCount}

# Install extra packages
# Set TimeZone, See: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/136#issuecomment-612751142
ARG TZ="Asia/Kolkata"
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN    apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
    && apk add --no-cache nss \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
    && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
    && mkdir -p /opt  \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
    && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

# TODO: plugins (later)
# && unzip -oq "/tmp/dependencies/JMeterPlugins-*.zip" -d $JMETER_HOME

# Set global PATH such that "jmeter" command is found
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

# Entrypoint has same signature as "jmeter" command

# RUN echo ${ENVIRONMENTNAME}
# RUN echo ${THREADUSERS}
# RUN echo ${THREADUSERS}
# RUN echo ${LOOPCOUNT}

WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}
CMD sh /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/entrypoint.sh && jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -JEnvName=${ENVIRONMENTNAME} -JthreadUsers=${THREADUSERS} -JrampUpPeriod=${RAMPUPPERIOD} -JloopCount=${LOOPCOUNT} -n -t /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/API${VERSION}Name.jmx -l /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/demoresults.jtl -e -o /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/demoresults -f
```

Comment: Two debugging things to try: in the `CMD` line you can `echo jmeter ...` to get a dump of the command line after the container shell parses it, or when you run the image you can `docker run ... jmeterimage env` to dump out the environment, both instead of actually running JMeter.  Does this point at anything in particular?

Comment: (You do not need `ARG` declarations for your runtime-only settings; you should not need to rebuild the Docker image on every execution, nor should you need `--no-cache` when you do rebuild it.)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion. I tried debugging using echo statement and it started working as now I used API${VERSION}Name.jmx and VERSION is getting replaced with correct value.